# Angular 2 Hierarchical Dependency Injection - Declaring root provider's dependencies outside of root?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular2-di

(Note I am using Angular 2 RC5)

For simplicity, I have an app like so:

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        RootService
    ],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**root.service.ts**

```
import Dependency1 from './somewhere'
import Dependency2 from './somewhere-else'

@Component({
    providers: [Dependency1, Dependency2]
})

@Injectable()
export class RootService {
    constructor(
        private dep1: Dependency1, 
        private dep2: Dependency2
    ) {...}
}
```

An example of a dependency is:

**dependency1.ts**

```
@Injectable()
    export class Dependency1{
    public doGroundbreakingSciencyStuff() {...}
}
```

---

My question is: Why, with the above, am I greeted with an error saying:
`No provider for PouchSync!`.

I can solve the problem by adding Dependency1 and Dependency2 to the `providers` array in **app.module.ts** like so:

**app.module.ts** (fixed)

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        RootService,
        Dependency1,
        Dependency2
    ],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

This just seems very ugly. Only `RootService` need to know about these dependencies. Am I doing something wrong here? Or can someone explain why it has to be this way? Surely, when injecting `RootService`, the injector can see that it's dependent on `Dependency1` and `Dependency2` and hence must inject those too, and hence they'll also be application wide singletons.

Comment: Could you please post real code, because your root service is not a service, but a component, and PouchSync is not used anywhere in the example code, so it's hard to understand what you're *actually* doing.

Comment: This is pretty close to my *real* code. In some functions in **root.service.ts**, I am going to call some functions on the two dependencies. The real code is too complicated and I think this illustrates the issue quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services **are not components**, so they can't have *@Component* decorator (which means - it is impossible to add providers array for service class). Conclusion? This code is wrong:

```
@Component({
    providers: [PouchSync, PouchArraySync]
})

@Injectable()
export class RootService {
    constructor(
        private dep1: Dependency1, 
        private dep2: Dependency2
    ) {...}
}
```

But your **second** example is made in angular 2 way.

You wrote that only `RootService` need to know about dependencies. So if these dependencies are not **reusable objects**, which should be injected in few pieces of your application, but only available in this class(!) - you should just create instances of them inside your service.

Comment: thanks for the answer - it's not strictly true that those services won't be reused. They might need to be injected elsewhere as the application expands. I also need to be able to mock them which I can't do if I don't inject them. Are you saying just to expose them on `RootService`?

Answer (score 0):

Any service that you want to use in your application must be added to the providers array. Adding a service to the root ngModule literally makes them available throughout the application.

When you say that 
"Surely, when injecting RootService, the injector can see that it's dependent on Dependency1 and Dependency2 and hence must inject those too, and hence they'll also be application wide singletons".

No injector will not add Dependency1  and Dependency2 automatically by only adding RootService. They have to be specifically added in providers array